# facebook DraweeView - remove image from cache

Tags: android, fresco

I am trying to remove image from cache in Facebook DraweeView. It is not removing the image and I can't understand why

```
Fresco.getImagePipeline().evictFromMemoryCache(uri1);
Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getImagePipeline().evictFromMemoryCache(uri1);
Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getMainDiskStorageCache().remove(new SimpleCacheKey(uri1.toString()));
Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getSmallImageDiskStorageCache().remove(new SimpleCacheKey(uri1.toString()));
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in http://frescolib.org/docs/caching.html#evicting-from-cache should work. If not, please file an issue on GitHub.